# Why can't I declare an object from array?

Tags: javascript

a simple example, Why does this give an error?

```
var zipped = [[0,1,2]];
var extracted = {};
var i = 0;
extracted[zipped[i][0]] = { zipped[i][1]: zipped[i][2] }
>>>Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [(…)
```

when this is perfectly fine?

```
 extracted[0] = { 1: 2 }
```

Comment: You cannot use expression as a key when initializing object property: `{ zipped[i][1]: ..`

Comment: Also `extracted[zipped[i][0]] = { 1 : zipped[i][2] }` works, really curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Javascript object literal syntax does not allow expressions in key parts. Keys are always literal. That's why you can write this:

```
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

And `foo` is not taken as a variable.

For variable keys, you always have to use this pattern:

```
var obj = {};
obj[varKey] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is invalid syntax.  A number is syntactically allowed in an object literal.  Arbitrary expressions are not.

Instead, you need to create the object, then set the attribute.

```
var obj = extracted[zipped[i][0]] = {};
obj[ zipped[i][1] ] = zipped[i][2];
```